# jVectorMap animation onRegionClick

Tags: jquery, animation, jvectormap

I'm using jVectorMap plugin and I'm very impressed by its usability and ease.

My question is: is there a way to insert some kind of animation on the onRegionClick callback function?

My map shows a list of publications for each country in a separate `<div>`.
Now I have:

```
$(function(){
    $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world',
        values: publications,
        scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        hoverColor: false,
        backgroundColor: '#383f47',
        onLabelShow: function(e, el, code){
            el.text(el.html()+' ('+code+') '+publications[code]);
        },
        onRegionClick: showPublications
    });
});
```

The map and the callback function work like a charm, but I'd like to add some kind of animation to give a better empathy to the showing list.

Ah, I use a js switch statement for the function "showPublications".

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery [**fadeIn()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method:

```
$('#myDiv').fadeIn(200);
```